# Iterate through list of labels and assign text through the code behind

Tags: c#, for-loop, label

The labels aren't populating with text and I'm not sure why. I need lbl0 to lbl6 filled with an incremented year.

```
        int year= Convert.ToInt32(hdnYear.Value);
        List<Label> lbl = new List<Label>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Label lbls = new Label();
            lbl.Add(lbls);
            int yearValue = (FY + i);

            string lblID = "lbl" + i;
            lbl[i].ID = lblID;
            lbl[i].Text = yearValue.ToString();
         }
```

Comment: you have not added the labels to the form or user control where you want to

Comment: Use `Controls.Add` instead of using a local variable to store the labels (notice that this will put them one above the other)

Comment: I believe I have added the labels to the page properly. I'm still stumped.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to use FindControl instead of trying to set the ID.

Answer (score 0):

you want to do something like this:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
 Label newLabel = new Label();
//set Properties of newLabel like ID, Content etc

 labels.Add(newLabel);
}
```

fyi: A TextBlock has a Text property, a Label has Content property